# How to use System.Net.Http.HttpClient to GET after POST with AllowAutoRedirect = true

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

Here is the code to create a client and POST an object. It is my understanding that setting AllowAutoRedirect = true would enable the ability for the client to follow the redirect then do a GET and I would be able to deserialize said object. My testing has proven unsuccessful so far. Is there something that I may have overlooked?

Web API endpoint:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Contact contact) {

    try {
        // Add user

        ...

        var msg = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        msg.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri + "/" + customer.Person.PersonID);
        return msg;
    } catch (ValidationException tve) {
        var apiError = new ApiResponseMessage { Message = "Invalid contact" };
        foreach (var message in FilterErrors(tve.Messages)) {
            if (message.Contains("required", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                apiError.Errors.Add(new ApiErrorMessage {
                    Code = ErrorCode.RequiredPropertyNotProvided,
                    Message = message
                });
            } else {
                apiError.Errors.Add(new ApiErrorMessage {
                    Code = ErrorCode.PropertyNotValid,
                    Message = message
                });
            }
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, apiError);
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
public Contact Post(Contact contact)
{
    try
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { AllowAutoRedirect = true};
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(APIServer);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-ApiKey", APIKey.ToString());

            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("v1/Contacts", contact).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Log.DebugFormat("Post v1/Contacts => {0} ({1})", response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);

                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contact>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                // This object is null

            }
            else
            {
                Log.ErrorFormat("Post v1/Contacts => {0} ({1})", response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);    
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiMessageResponse>(
                        response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);                      
            }


        }

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Log.Error(exception);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Wireshark logs.

POST /v1/Contacts HTTP/1.1  (application/json)
HTTP/1.1 201 Created 
Location: http://api01.example.com/v1/Contacts/10135052

and that's it, no GET (http://api01.example.com/v1/Contacts/10135052) after as far as I can tell.

Comment: Can you show us the logs? Are you sure you are getting a 302?

Comment: @JoshC. Updated with trace info.

Comment: Won't a redirect (3xx) response to a POST cause the client to re-issue the original request (the POST, not GET)? If you want a POST followed by a GET, I think you will have to do 2 requests. How you abstract away the logic behind the 2 requests is up to you.

Comment: @JesseWebb Yeah, I have to agree, I think this is going to require to calls. Now I need to parse the Location value.

Comment: PRG is a common pattern, and yes it will require two requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the log trace you added, it looks like the response from the POST is a 201 (Created); there is no redirect. The response does contain a URL (either in a header or the body, hard to tell) but it will not mean anything special. Your client will need to parse the URL itself and issue the subsequent GET request explicitly.

Comment: Actually since it looks like Stephen owns the server, why not just return HttpStatusCode.Redirect